How to solve Netsuite Error Related to location?
Not able to sync Invoice with NetSuite getting location referenvce error, not sure how to set it up or what value to use.
I am using multi entity structure.
Request
  <env:Body>
<platformMsgs:add>
  <platformMsgs:record xsi:type="tranSales:Invoice">
    <tranSales:tranId>INV-00082</tranSales:tranId>
    <tranSales:entity internalId="42264"/>
    <tranSales:tranDate>2025-01-08T00:00:00-08:00</tranSales:tranDate>
    <tranSales:dueDate>2025-01-08T00:00:00-08:00</tranSales:dueDate>
    <tranSales:endDate>2025-02-07T00:00:00-08:00</tranSales:endDate>
    <tranSales:currency internalId="1"/>
    <tranSales:exchangeRate>1.0</tranSales:exchangeRate>
    <tranSales:taxTotal>0.00</tranSales:taxTotal>
    <tranSales:billingAddress/>
    <tranSales:shippingAddress/>
    <tranSales:account internalId="229"/>
    <tranSales:terms internalId="4"/>
    <tranSales:subsidiary internalId="1"/>
    <tranSales:itemList>
      <tranSales:item>
        <tranSales:line>1</tranSales:line>
        <tranSales:description>Chrome NetSuite</tranSales:description>
        <tranSales:isTaxable>false</tranSales:isTaxable>
        <tranSales:rate>100.0</tranSales:rate>
        <tranSales:quantity>1.0</tranSales:quantity>
        <tranSales:item internalId="15826"/>
      </tranSales:item>
      <tranSales:item>
        <tranSales:line>2</tranSales:line>
        <tranSales:description>Chrome NetSuite</tranSales:description>
        <tranSales:isTaxable>false</tranSales:isTaxable>
        <tranSales:rate>100.0</tranSales:rate>
        <tranSales:quantity>1.0</tranSales:quantity>
        <tranSales:item internalId="15826"/>
      </tranSales:item>
    </tranSales:itemList>
  </platformMsgs:record>
</platformMsgs:add>

</env:Body>
Response
<soapenv:Body>
<addResponse xmlns="urn:messages_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
  <writeResponse>
    <platformCore:status xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" isSuccess="false">
      <platformCore:statusDetail type="ERROR">
        <platformCore:code>INVALID_KEY_OR_REF</platformCore:code>
        <platformCore:message>You have entered an Invalid Field Value 1 for the following field: location.</platformCore:message>
      </platformCore:statusDetail>
    </platformCore:status>
  </writeResponse>
</addResponse>

</soapenv:Body>
If i force hardcode location attribute like
<tranSales:location internalId="1"/>

Gets this error
Invalid location reference key 1 for subsidiary 1.

Not able to indentify the problem.
Setup > Company > Classification > Location option is also not present, location feature is enabled.
I can see some staging location or Geolocation.
Can anyone help on this.

It seems that the location isn't available for your subsidiary
You can go to Setup > Company > Location > Select your location and check you subsidiary
The location is a standard segment, so if you can see it, it maybe that:

It has been renamed. (Setup > Company > Rename Records/Transactions > Check location)
It you may need to enable the feature (Setup > Company > Enable feature > Company > Check location box)

